# How to sort MongoDB collection with day from createdAt field with another field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way i can sort a collection descending of `day` from an `createdAt` field.

What I'm expecting is that, I wanted to sort contents based on created `day` from createdAt field with `rating` field. So that i will get all the good rated content for each day

If i do `{ rating: -1, createdAt: -1 }` i'm not getting the desired output

Comment: Please share the sample collections. I believe you have to use `$group` here for each day but cannot say anything before seeing your sample collection

Comment: @Ashh It's pretty straightforward, { _id, rating, createdAt, updatedAt, and other fields },